# ubuntu dual boot 14.04 dell inspiron - wifi does not work

Tags: 14.04, wireless, dell, inspiron

My computer is the following: Dell - Inspiron 15 - 7000 Series - Model: 7559

Display:

15.6" Full HD display with webcam Performance:

Intel Core i5-6300HQ Processor 8GB RAM 256GB Solid State Drive (SSD) NVIDIA GeForce GTX, 960M 4GB Graphics

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 wifi isnt working because I cant find wifi driver.

```
infy@infy:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3165] (rev 79)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4410]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command. And also please ask one question at a time.

Comment: that code will make my wifi work ?

Comment: That will show what wifi adapter you have.

Comment: how to use it then ? please tell me the whole process . Thank you

Comment: Post the command to terminal, press Enter, edit your question and post the output there.

Comment: i entered the command !! It showed the driver. But how should i use it ? 
Is there any specific command for that? And i didnt understand what do you mean by "edit your question and post the output there.".. 
please elaborate

Comment: Please post the output here so I CAN SEE IT. Then I will suggest what to do next. You can [edit] your question and post information there. What is not clear?

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade the kernel.

Connect to internet by wire or some other way and run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.156_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.156_all.deb
sudo cp /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode  /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3165-13.ucode
```

and reboot.

Comment: I added a couple commands. I am not sure 14.04 has the firmware for that adapter. It will work if you do not make mistakes.