# Networking - Dell Gaming - Ubuntu 14.04 WiFi (Wireless) not working - Kernel issue

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, wireless, kernel

I recently installed 14.04 on my Dell gaming laptop. This [link](http://www.dell.com/en-us/member/shop/dell-laptops/inspiron-15-7000-gaming/spd/inspiron-15-7577-laptop/dncwfs618h) gives my laptop specs.

As the title suggests, the Wireless connection isn't working (isn't visible for access). I scoured the net for possible solutions. I found 3 relevant links on askUbuntu -

1. [No wifi/ethernet on fresh Ubuntu 14.04 lts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/934834/no-wifi-ethernet-on-fresh-ubuntu-14-04-lts/934859?newreg=3a86d15ed8594034a96bb55e2d637532) suggests that 14.04 is too old for my laptop configuration and hence I should be installing 16.04. However, I need 14.04 itself, since I need it mainly to work on [ROS Indigo](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu) which is compatible only with 14.04.
2. [Wifi not working (Intel) on HP Spectre x360 13](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858546/wifi-not-working-intel-on-hp-spectre-x360-13) suggests that I should be installing a 4.8.14 kernel to solve this issue. But one of the links in the answer is broken. I'm not sure whether I should go ahead with the procedure given.
3. [ubuntu dual boot 14.04 dell inspiron - wifi does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/735479/ubuntu-dual-boot-14-04-dell-inspiron-wifi-does-not-work) again suggests that I should be updating my kernel. Again, I'm not sure whether that's the procedure I should be following since that is not the exact network controller I have.

Here are some relevant outputs from my system -

```
srinidhi@srinidhi-Inspiron-7577:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2  
3c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fd] (rev 78)    
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0050]
```

Here is the Network controller output of lspci -v

```
3c:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 24fd (rev 78)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0050   
Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255   
Memory at dd100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=8K]  
Capabilities: access denied
```

Here is my lsusb output

```
srinidhi@srinidhi-Inspiron-7577:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub   
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04e8:6863 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9500 [Galaxy S4] / GT-I9250 [Galaxy Nexus] (network tethering)   
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub   
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub   
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 27c6:5301     
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp.    
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:6718 Microdia    
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04ca:00a5 Lite-On Technology Corp.    
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I would greatly appreciate anyone to help me out with fixing this as I am not sure how to solve this issue. I've worked with ubuntu before in my undergrad mainly for ROS and I desperately need it working for grad school now. Thanks.

Comment: Gotcha. I have completed the changes.

Comment: Thanks! Now about point (2), the `linux-firmware` package that's linked was the latest at the time the answer was written (the one for 16.10). You can use a newer version, say the one for 17.04: https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/all/linux-firmware/download

Comment: @muru your link (not personal) has a link titled "security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu" which is not found.

Comment: @muru the link you gave has a broken link inside it.

Comment: Oh, ha, 17.04 is also EOL, like 16.10. Here's the link for 17.10, which should work: https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/all/linux-firmware/download

Comment: According to http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/, packages are available for all currently-supported releases of Ubuntu. You are apparently NOT stuck with 14.04.

Comment: I just edited the linked answer to provide an updated link for the firmware. I suggest that you proceed.

Comment: @user535733 That may be true, but this [link](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu) explicitly states that "ROS Indigo **ONLY** supports Saucy (13.10) and Trusty (14.04) for debian packages."

Comment: Perhaps you should ask ROS why they create loads of packages for current releases of Ubuntu...that they don't support. There is a significant probability that the line you quote is a bit out-of-date.

Comment: @user535733 ROS actually releases newer versions every year. The latest version of ROS is Lunar, however the current recommended version of ROS is Kinetic which is compatible only with  Wily (Ubuntu 15.10), Xenial (Ubuntu 16.04) and Jessie (Debian 8) for debian packages. That line in Indigo installation page is not out of date as I tried installing Indigo in Xenial (16.04) and it didn't function properly. As to why I prefer Indigo, most of the academia and industries still prefer Indigo and the book I refer to learn ROS teaches based on Indigo. Hence all this hassle.